# Restoring DB from pg_basebackup I get 'role "postgres" does not exist' error on new DB

Tags: postgresql, backup, psql

I do it for the first time. On the main server I've set archive_mode getting my WAL files and do base backups via cron with the following command:

`pg_basebackup -h localhost -U <user> -Ft -z -D /var/log/postgresql/base_backup_$(date +\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M)/`: It creates base backup and additional WAL files.

On secondary server I run new posgres 10.10 container with backup and WALs mounted via volume without initial DB creation, using bash:

`docker run --entrypoint=bash -ti -e  POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -v <WAL and backup dir on the host>:/tmp/pg_data postgres:10.10`

In container I create base PG dir, unpack base backup with WALs there. Create recovery.conf file, take care about permission and ownerships and finally start my new PG server with this command under `postgres` user:

`/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl -D /pg_base start`

It gives me no errors:

```
waiting for server to start....2022-04-14 15:48:35.521 UTC [26] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-04-14 15:48:35.521 UTC [26] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-04-14 15:48:35.555 UTC [26] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-04-14 15:48:35.611 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2022-04-14 15:11:20 UTC
2022-04-14 15:48:35.832 UTC [27] LOG:  starting point-in-time recovery to 2022-04-14 15:48:27+00
2022-04-14 15:48:35.870 UTC [27] LOG:  restored log file "00000001000001250000007A" from archive
2022-04-14 15:48:36.279 UTC [27] LOG:  redo starts at 125/7A000028
2022-04-14 15:48:36.356 UTC [27] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 125/7A62A098
2022-04-14 15:48:36.357 UTC [26] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
 done
server started
```

`recovery.conf` is being renamed to `recovery.done`. I do not "replay", or restore these additional real time WAL files which I have mounted to the container also yet. Because, at this point, I expect postgres up and running having the state of the main server at least by the time of base backup creation.

I check it trying to connect to postgres but it fails because neither `postgres` nor `root` roles (DB users) are not found in new DB:

`docker exec <container_name> psql -U postgres`

Output is:
`psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

User `postgres` exists on the master DB. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: This doesn't sound possible, I suspect you are not describing the problem accurately.  If the 'postgres' database user (*not* OS user) exists on the master, why aren't you using it to take the backup?  What if you try to connect to the clone as the censored username you used to take the backup?

Comment: Thanks @jjanes! Master server has only this custom user. I can login on Slave DB  to logical DB under this user and all the data seems to be at the right place. Tere is no `postgres` user on Master DB instance, it has been removed. Thanks a lot. Problem solved.